# Using INTO in COLLECT while also using AGGREGATE. Can it be done?

Tags: arangodb

The shape of the documents I'm using look similar to this:

```
{
 "survey_id": 123,
  "numerical_answers": [
    {
      "component_id": 345,
      "number": 5,
    },
    {
      "component_id": 346,
      "number": 5,
    }
  ]
}
```

The output of ArangoDB should look like this:

```
[
  {
    "component_id": 345,
    "distribution": [
      {
        "component_id": 345,
        "score": null,
        "total": 42
      },
      {
        "component_id": 345,
        "score": 1,
        "total": 76
      },
      {
        "component_id": 345,
        "score": 2,
        "total": 37
      },
      {
        "component_id": 345,
        "score": 3,
        "total": 40
      },
      {
        "component_id": 345,
        "score": 4,
        "total": 93
      },
      {
        "component_id": 345,
        "score": 5,
        "total": 212
      }
    ],
    "total": 500,
    "avg": 3.404
  }
]
```

My AQL looks like this:

```
FOR doc IN @@collection
  FILTER doc.`survey_id` == @survey_id

  LET componentScoreGroup = {
    component_id: @component_id,
    score: FIRST(doc.numerical_answers[* filter CURRENT.component_id == @component_id return CURRENT.number])
  }

  COLLECT component_id = componentScoreGroup.component_id, score = componentScoreGroup.score WITH COUNT INTO total

  LET distribution = {
    component_id: component_id,
    score: score,
    total: total
  }

  COLLECT component_id2 = distribution.component_id into groups keep distribution

  LET finalTotal = sum(groups[*].distribution.total), 
      summedScore = sum(groups[* return CURRENT.distribution.score * CURRENT.distribution.total])

  RETURN {
    component_id: component_id2,
    distribution: groups[*].distribution,
    total: finalTotal,
    avg: summedScore / finalTotal
  }
```

I would like to use the more performant `AGGREGATE` syntax in the `COLLECT` but I'm not sure I can because I also want to pull in the `distribution` content in the final return.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a description of what you are trying to achieve? What do the different fields in the output mean in relation to the input data?

Comment: I would like o use the more performant `AGGREGATE` syntax when doing the collection. But if I do that, I can't use the `INTO groups KEEP distribution` to then add the `distribution` to the `RETURN`.  So I'm wondering if there is a trick in AQL to still use the `AGGREGATE` syntax and _also_ still be able to have access to previously defined `distribution` so I add it to the final output.  The above AQL _does_ work, but I think it _could_ be more performant.

Comment: Ok, but in order to help come up with an alternate method , it would be good to have a description of what is the business goal of what you are doing. So, it would be good if you edit the question and put a paragraph or two about what this code is being used for, what the input means and what the output means. You have very well described what your technical goal is, which is good. But right now it is like someone putting all his LEGO pieces on the floor and asking his friend to go build it, without telling him what he is supposed to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this closer to what you are looking for?

```
FOR doc IN @@collection
  FILTER doc.survey_id == @survey_id

     LET componentScoreGroup = {
          component_id: @component_id,
          score: FIRST(doc.numerical_answers[* filter CURRENT.component_id == @component_id return CURRENT.number])
        }

    COLLECT id = componentScoreGroup.component_id
    AGGREGATE avg = AVG(componentScoreGroup.score),
              total = SUM(componentScoreGroup.score)
    INTO group
    return { "id" : id , "avg" : avg , "total" : total, "number" : LENGTH(group), "group" : group}
```

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know you could do an `INTO` _after_ the `AGGREGATE`.  I think I tried that but I was also adding a `KEEP` which doesn't seem to work. If you remove the `KEEP` it works fine.  Wonder why that is?  Anyway, thanks a ton for your answer!

Comment: Hi, the missing variant has been added to the documentation https://github.com/arangodb/docs/pull/107. Unfortunately `KEEP` is not possible in all places.